# Why min Heap of Python is not returning the minimum value here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, heap

I printed out every iteration. The contents of the list are perfect. But for some reason heappop is returning -8 val even though there is -15 in the list. Help me out

```
class FoodRatings:

    def __init__(self, foods: List[str], cuisines: List[str], ratings: List[int]):
        
        self.find_cuisine = defaultdict()
        self.hashset = defaultdict(list)
        
        for f, c, r in zip(foods, cuisines, ratings):
            self.find_cuisine[f] = (c, r)
            heapq.heappush(self.hashset[c], (-r, f))    
  
    def changeRating(self, food: str, newRating: int) -> None:

        c, r = self.find_cuisine[food]
        self.hashset[c].remove((-r, food))
        heapq.heappush(self.hashset[c], (-newRating, food))
        self.find_cuisine[food] = (c, newRating)

    def highestRated(self, cuisine: str) -> str:
        
        r, f =  heapq.heappop(self.hashset[cuisine])
        heapq.heappush(self.hashset[cuisine], (r, f))
        return f
```

> Input:

foods = ["czopaaeyl","lxoozsbh","kbaxapl"],

cuisines = ["dmnuqeatj","dmnuqeatj","dmnuqeatj"],

ratings = [11,2,15]],

> calls

"FoodRatings"

"changeRating" - ["czopaaeyl",12],

"highestRated" - ["dmnuqeatj"],

"changeRating" - ["kbaxapl",8],

"changeRating" - ["lxoozsbh",5],

"highestRated" - ["dmnuqeatj"],

> My output: [null,null,"kbaxapl",null,null,"kbaxapl"]

> Expected Output: [null,null,"kbaxapl",null,null,"czopaaeyl"]

Comment: please provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: A clearer way to show the calls and outputs you had would be a text copy of a REPL session showing those calls and outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only mutate a heap using the `heapq` methods. By calling `remove` you  bring inconsistency to the tree, as the indexes of nodes are altered, changing parent-child relationships, and thereby likely breaking the heap property at one or more places in the tree.

What you can do is to *not* remove the node you want to replace, but to *mark* it as deleted, without changing its ordering. Then, if ever that node bubbles up to the top of the tree, and you want to get the top value, only *then* remove it through a `heappop` call. Keep doing this until the top value is a node that was not marked as deleted.

To mark a node as deleted, you cannot use an (immutable) tuple. Use a list instead. And then the marking can consist of extending such a list with a 3rd dummy value. The length of 3 will distinguish it from the expected length of 2.

Here is the modified code with comments where changes were made:

```
class FoodRatings:
    def __init__(self, foods: List[str], cuisines: List[str], ratings: List[int]):
        self.find_cuisine = defaultdict()
        self.hashset = defaultdict(list)
        for f, c, r in zip(foods, cuisines, ratings):
            node = [-r, f]  # Use a mutable list instead of tuple
            self.find_cuisine[f] = (c, node)  # Add reference to that node
            heapq.heappush(self.hashset[c], node)
  
    def changeRating(self, food: str, newRating: int) -> None:
        c, node = self.find_cuisine[food]
        node.append("deleted")  # Don't remove, but mark as deleted
        node = [-newRating, food]  # Create new node
        heapq.heappush(self.hashset[c], node)
        self.find_cuisine[food] = (c, node)

    def highestRated(self, cuisine: str) -> str:
        while self.hashset[cuisine] and len(self.hashset[cuisine][0]) > 2:
            heapq.heappop(self.hashset[cuisine])  # Ignore deleted nodes
        if self.hashset[cuisine]:
            return self.hashset[cuisine][0][1]  # Just peek at index 0
```

Comment: My code works now. I learned something new today. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A heapq list is a tree that just happens to be stored in a list, not a sorted list. Python won't stop you from removing an element from the middle of it using `list.remove`, but doing that can scramble the tree so that it no longer gives the right results. One way to fix that is to call `heapq.heapify` on the list after you change it.

Also note that you don't need to pop and re-push just to look at the lowest element. The lowest element is at index 0.